# Pregunta y respuesta por UDP en Android

Tags: android

En mi app estoy realizando un cliente UDP el cual interroga a un servidor y este debe de responder inmediatamente de no ser así debe de cerrar la conexión después de 10 seg para enviar el siguiente comando de interrogación, he colocado el lazo while (run) pero me gustaría reemplazar esto para que salga del lazo cuando se cumple el tiempo de 10 seg o llegue el mensaje de respuesta, por favor alguien me podría decir cómo hacer esto?

Aquí está mi código

```
public void run() {
        boolean run = true;
        try {
            DatagramSocket udpSocket = new DatagramSocket( SERVER_PORT );
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName( SERVER_ADDRESS );
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length, serverAddr, SERVER_PORT );
            udpSocket.send( packet );
            while (run) {
                try {
                    byte[] message = new byte[8000];
                    packet = new DatagramPacket( message, message.length );
                    udpSocket.setSoTimeout( 100 );
                    udpSocket.receive( packet );
                    String text = new String( message, 0, packet.getLength() );
                    mDumpTextView.append( text + "\n" );
                    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo( 0, mDumpTextView.getBottom() );
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    Log.e("Timeout Exception","ERROR UDP Connection:",e);
                    run = false;
                    udpSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("IOException Exception","ERROR UDP Connection:",e);
                    run = false;
                    udpSocket.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e( "Socket Open:", "Error:", e );
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Según te entiendo, quieres como un contador con el cual pasados 10 segundos cierre el lazo del run?

Comment: o que al recibir el dato también se cierre

Answer (score 0):

Podría ayudarte con un contador de tiempo.

Creas la clase

```
public class Contador extends CountDownTimer {

    public Contador(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {/////CUANDO SE TERMINA EL CONTEO DEL TIEMPO
        //Cuando llegue acá cierras el lazo de conexión
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int segundos = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);///CADA VEZ QUE PASA UN SEGUNDO LLEGA ACA
    }

}
```

Lo inicializas y luego lo construyes:

`Contador counter = new Contador(tiempo,10000);
counter.start();//Inicias el conteo cuando empieces la consulta al servidor`

Alguien mas podría ayudarte para identificar cuando recibas la información, entonces si recibes la información antes de los 10 segundos cerrarías el contador con `counter.cancel();` que cerraría el lazo de conexión directamente.